# How can i keep the same function with different argument type

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, matrix, overriding

Mr
I have developed this function to disply matrices.
I don't want to write the function again, perhaps i have many matrices with different arguments type.

```
private void displyMatrix(int matrix[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

What happens if i have another matrix with double argument?
Do i have to write the function again, or there is another method.
Thanks

Comment: Check out what Overloading in java is.
Of course, you can have a lot of methods doing the same thing with different types of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can create method like this with help of generics.

```
public <T> void print(T[][] matrix) {
   for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

The only limitation would be, you need to use wrapper class `Integer` instead of primitive `int`.

```
Integer[][] integers = new Integer[][]{ new Integer[] {1, 2}};

Double[][] doubles = new Double[][]{ new Double[] {1.0, 2.0}};

print(integers);
print(doubles);
```

Comment: You can even ensure that `T` is a numeric value using `<T extends Number>` so it could be only used with `Integer`, `Double` and so on :)

Comment: @NiziL as the method under consideration basically printing data, as long as there is no operation specific to number, and matrix could be anything (i.e custom object), it should be ok without boundaries. what do you think?

Comment: Totally agree ! I heard matrix, saw an `int`, and was directly thinking about math... too much extrapolation from my side.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful, perhaps if i change from int to Integer, the code will be slow?  In case of large code